# How to Use Textbox property Value in C#

Tags: c#

I have some problem in using textbox value that I get from `get set` accessors in C#. I have user control called `SerahTerima` that the textBox1 is shown to `Overview` form. After that, I want to show data to datagridview based on the textbox value that shown in `Overview` form but it's failed. How can I do ?

[image: IMG1]

**SerahTerima.cs**

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Overview ov = new Overview();
            var textBoxContent = this.textBox7.Text;
            var parent = this.Parent as Overview;
            ov.ID2 = textBoxContent;
            ov.ShowDialog();
        }
```

**Overview.cs**

```
public string ID2
        {
                set { textBox1.Text = value; }
            }

private void TampilOverview()
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from alokasi_kunci", connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            connection.Open();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr2["tim"].ToString() == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    int aa = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                    dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[0].Value = dr2["kelompok"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[2].Value = dr2["pic"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[3].Value = dr2["keterangan"].ToString();
                }

            }
            connection.Close();
    }
```

When i run toogle breakpoint in textBox1, there is null value.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What variable/argument exactly has a `null` value? Which code line exactly did you place your breakpoint on. Is textBox7 actually the correct TextBox to get the string from? Maybe you made a mistake and the TextBox you want to get the text from is not textBox7, but perhaps textBox6, or textBox8. Or maybe textBox5... who knows...

Comment: By the way, not having a getter for your property is not related to your problem. The first comment is a red herring. But still, i agree in a way with the 1st comment that a getter-less property is highly unusual and unconventional, and it is possibly confusing to other people having to read/maintain/use your code involving that property...

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Oh i am really sorry. textBox1.Text has a null value @elgonzo

Comment: Is the `value` argument passed into the property setter already `null` or not `null`? You will have to run your progrsam in the debugger and [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) your code, basically tracing back the textBox1.Text value `null` back to whatever is the origin where this particular `null` value first appears... Unfortunately, we can't do this for you :-(